# Expand column elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I've a dataframe column like this:

```
dataframe['entries_from'][0]

[{'trackable_name': 'Grinding Teeth',
  'trackable_type': 'Symptom',
  'trackable_value': '2'},
 {'trackable_name': 'Hip pain',
  'trackable_type': 'Symptom',
  'trackable_value': '3'},
 {'trackable_name': 'Ankle pain',
  'trackable_type': 'Symptom',
  'trackable_value': '2'},
 {'trackable_name': 'Rib pain',
  'trackable_type': 'Condition',
  'trackable_value': '4'},
 {'trackable_name': 'Mental fatigue',
  'trackable_type': 'Weather',
  'trackable_value': '2'},
 {'trackable_name': 'Chronic pain',
  'trackable_type': 'Treatment',
  'trackable_value': '4'}]
```

I want to expand this column and add as new columns to the existing data frame.

```
Symptom                                Treatment      Weather          Condition
Grinding Teeth, Hip pain, Ankle pain   Chronic pain   Mental Fatigue   Rib pain
```

I wrote

```
for index, row in dataframe['entries_from'].items():
  for d in row:
    for key, value in d.items():
      if value == 'Symptom':
        dataframe['Symptom_from'] = d.get("trackable_name")
```

but got the result like this

```
0       Unwanted Thoughts
1       Unwanted Thoughts
2       Unwanted Thoughts
3       Unwanted Thoughts
4       Unwanted Thoughts
              ...        
8565    Unwanted Thoughts
8566    Unwanted Thoughts
8567    Unwanted Thoughts
8568    Unwanted Thoughts
8569    Unwanted Thoughts
Name: Symptom_from, Length: 8570, dtype: object
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct for the most part. Create a temporary `list` to collect all the `Symptoms` from the `list` of `dict`.

```
for index, row in dataframe['entries_from'].items():
    symptoms = []
    for d in row:
        for key, value in d.items():
            if value == 'Symptom':
                symptoms.append( d.get("trackable_name"))
            elif value == 'Condition':
                dataframe['Condition'] =  d.get("trackable_name")
            elif value == 'Weather':
                dataframe['Weather'] =  d.get("trackable_name")
            elif value == 'Treatment':
                dataframe['Treatment'] =  d.get("trackable_name")
        dataframe['Symptom_from'] = str(symptoms)
```